# How can I get Google Play on my Kindle Fire 5th gen?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

How can I install google play on my Kindle Fire 5th generation?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the part where a lot of stuff would need to be done. However, there is a tool, [SuperTool.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/amazon-fire/development/amazon-fire-5th-gen-supertool-root-t3272695) You will need Fire OS 5.1.2 (BE AWARE! it may not tell you the full version in system>about device.)

To be brief, Supertool allows users to install ADB, (Android Debug Bridge) Root their devices, block OTA updates (which kills off root access, among other things) and, ***it lets you install Google Play***.

Let us know how it goes! And I will say it again: ***you must be on Fire OS 5.1.2. Downgrading results in a hard-brick, and all other versions have a secured bootloader. Its like homebrew, but the war between the big companies and the modders almost never moves.***